# what is blackberry entreprise server?

Tags: blackberry

can anyone explain me the what would happen when one sends an Http request from a blackberry device?

I heard so many things and i got confused with the terms MDS conncetion services and so on.I even heard we need to change some settings in the BES to receive the http request. Is it really needed to change the settings ?

Please explain in a clear way as im new to the blackberry application development.

Answer (score 1):

BES: Think of it as a private network composed of all the BB devices of an organization. Corporations usually run their own BES servers which are placed inside their own network and under their control. Each device in the BES can only connect to devices in this network, the BES server, and those network resources accesible through the BES server (typically other corporate application servers). Communications are encrypted. Also provides integration with enterprise mail systems. In addition, every BB in a BES is managed by the BES admin, who has control over the policies for each device - he can disable GPS or internet for a given device, for instance. He can also remotely deploy or delete applications from a device.

MDS: It is a component of the BES.

BIS: This is aimed to particular customers. When your BB is in BIS, your data is sent compressed to a RIM server that relays it to the destination. It's a proxy. It's also what allows for push mail and messages. For your BB to be in BIS, you need to contract it through you mobile carrier.

More info:
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/7335/BES_overview_658676_11.jsp

Comment: Thanks for the reply...i got it but one last doubt please..whenever an http request is made from my application then it is going to hit the BES? is it?

Comment: No not necessarily. It may not at all hit the BES. You need to indicate the kind of internet connection the http should pass from. If you want the app to make the http connection via Wifi, you can indicate in your code HttpTransport httpt = new HttpTransport(URL+";interface=wifi"); This http request is made without hitting the BES. I will add seperately some lines of code to make a call to the method and select the kind of connection available. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Agree with @Sarah, but that's the old way of opening connections. Use the newest `ConnectionManager` whenever possible. You can set the preferred transport using the enum in `TransportInfo` so you no longer have to append tricky suffixes in URLs.

Comment: sorry for the trouble, im not getting exactly what i asked for.Please put it in a layman terms. My concern is, what it would happen at the backend when i make a http request to hit my client server?..when i try to do this im getting an 401 response code.please help me.

Comment: 401 Unauthorized. Probably you are hitting the client server but it requires authentication.

Comment: i have the access even im getting the same response code..that's my concern is about..do i need to change anything in the BES..because im sending the credentilas from here but how does BES gets to know that the username and password are at some particluar place in the request

Comment: Usually you don't need to change config in the BES, other than ensuring devices can open connections. If this were a BES permission problem you'd be getting a `ControlledAccessException`. If it were a networking problem you'd get a 400 or a timeout. BES shouldn't be changing http auth headers nor content.

Answer (score 0):

When one sends an Http request from a BlackBerry device, BlackBerry client app connects to a webservice/servlet using HTTP and transfers byte[] from client –> servlet –> client. The client app checks for network coverage first, before trying to connect.

There are various ways to create an HTTP networking connection from your BlackBerry device to an HTTP server (web service, servlet, etc). This includes sending Http request over Wifi, APN/Direct TCP, BlackBerry Internet Service (BIS) and BlackBerry Enterprise Server (BES/MDS) which requires your BlackBerry to be connected to a BES.

The BlackBerry Mobile Data System (MDS) is a flexible framework for application development and a component of the BlackBerry Enterprise Server (BES). The BlackBerry MDS offers security, wireless connectivity, and manageability options. The BlackBerry MDS Services are included in the BlackBerry Enterprise Server software and handle all browser or connection requests and route the requests accordingly.  Unlike BIS or other connections, data flowing between the BlackBerry smartphone and BlackBerry Enterprise Server is encrypted and a connection made through BlackBerry MDS provides roaming across wireless service providers that support BlackBerry smartphone service. Since this connection requires the handset to be registered in the BES, it poses some restrictions to running the app as not every user might be registered. Therefore, when creating your application for Http request, you can key in options to detect the connections available (Wifi,TCP,BIS,MDS etc) and prioritizing the method to make the request.

The following method can be called to make the http request with an available connection. First preference is given to Wifi, second to BIS, third to TCP and finally to MDS.

```java
public String checkInternetConnection()
{
    String connectionString = null;
    if ((WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED)&& RadioInfo.areWAFsSupported(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN))
    {
        //WiFi is available
        connectionString = ";interface=wifi";
    }
    // Is the carrier network the only way to connect?
    else if((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT)
    {
        //Carrier coverage
        String carrierUid = getCarrierBIBSUid();
        if(carrierUid == null)
        {
            // Has carrier coverage, but not BIBS. So use the carrier's TCP network
            connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
        }
        else
        {
            // otherwise, use the Uid to construct a valid carrier BIBS request
            connectionString = ";deviceside=false;connectionUID="+carrierUid + ";ConnectionType=mds-public";
        }
    }
    // Check for an MDS connection instead (BlackBerry Enterprise Server)
    else if((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS)
    {
        connectionString = ";deviceside=false";
    }
    // If there is no connection available abort to avoid bugging the user unnecssarily.
    else if(CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_NONE)
    {
        Dialog.alert("There is no available connection.");
    }
    return connectionString;
}

/**
 * Looks through the phone's service book for a carrier provided BIBS network
 * @return The uid used to connect to that network.
 */
public String getCarrierBIBSUid()
{
    ServiceRecord[] records = ServiceBook.getSB().getRecords();
    int currentRecord;
    for(currentRecord = 0; currentRecord < records.length; currentRecord++)
    {
        if(records[currentRecord].getCid().toLowerCase().equals("ippp"))
        {
            if(records[currentRecord].getName().toLowerCase().indexOf("bibs") >= 0)
            {
                return records[currentRecord].getUid();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...i got it but one last doubt please..whenever an http request is made from my application then it is going to hit the BES? is it?

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a method to make an http request through any of the available connections.

Comment: Is it really needed to put these many types of connections before my application hits the url mentioned in the request?

Comment: Not necessarily, you could just hard code one of the preferred method you want to use. This is only useful if you want to give your app the liberty to make an http request by any of the available options.

Comment: sorry for the trouble, im not getting exactly what i asked for.Please put it in a layman terms. My concern is, what it would happen at the backend when i make a http request to hit my client server?..when i try to do this im getting an 401 response code.please help me.

Comment: Like I stated in my answer, When one sends an Http request from a BlackBerry device, BlackBerry client app connects to a webservice/servlet using HTTP and transfers byte[] from client –> servlet –> client. The 401 Unauthorized HTTP status code means that the page you were trying to access can not be loaded until you first log on with a valid username and password. In order to avoid gettings this response code, make sure the url is correct and you are passing the login credentials:
request.addProperty("username", user_id);
request.addProperty("password", password);